# Have there been instances of a monarchy being reintroduced after being abolished?

Tags: monarchy

This question is partly inspired by [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42890/how-might-the-united-kingdom-become-a-republic) question.

Abolishing monarchies is traditionally done via a revolution (I'm not aware of any instances of the converse). If the revolutions turn out violent, like in France and Russia, the royals and possibly other nobles tend to get executed. However, there are also cases, notably [Serbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander,_Crown_Prince_of_Yugoslavia), where a viable descendant is available. So, basically, once a monarchy is abolished, there are two options: there either are (direct or otherwise) descendants of the royal family and/or other noble families left or there aren't.

Have there been instances of a monarchy being reintroduced in a country in either of those cases?

I imagine that it would be somewhat harder to just "reinvent" some royal family than to reinstate an already living one. There is also the possibility of elected monarchs, but I think that is just theoretical. In any case, there must be political incentive to do so, in the case of a republic, some party must somehow push trough the required constitutional and other changes. The required support would presumably imply that they are also the ruling party and probably that he current head of state is a dominant member of that party, so basically they would undermine their own power, which is a hard thing for politicians to do.

Comment: Royal families tend to have a wide spread (i.e. lots of siblings and cousins, second cousins, etc.) so it'll be very rare for a royal family to be completely eliminated. Also you've given a couple of examples in the question, England (from the link) and France, which both restored a monarchy after their respective abolition - why don't these fit your criteria?

Comment: Please indicate why eg Augustus/Rome, Cromwell/England, Bourbon/France, Pu Yi/China do not fit your inquiry. You mean shortly / the same family?

Comment: Three easy ones off the top of my head: Britain, France, Spain.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Might check Wikipedia for the English restoration.  I can't do it from my cell phone.  This is one of the cases where it is very helpful to show the research you have done to a oid dozens of overlapping replies.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of restored monarchies, which also includes Cambodia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abolition_of_monarchy#Current_monarchies_that_were_abolished_and_then_restored

Comment: Short answer Yes.  Have you heard of the 1st & 2nd French, Mexican, and Haitian Empires?  Emperor Trajan annexed Armenia but his successor Hadrian restored the Armenian monarchy.  Centuries later Armenia was divided between Rome and Persia and centuries after that the kingdom of Armenia was restored.

Comment: There's other examples: Greece, abolished 1922, restored 1935, abolished again 1974. China abolished 1912, restored 1916, abolished 1916, restored 1917, abolished again 1917. Hungary abolished 1918 restored 1919, abolished again 1946. Haiti abolished 1806, restored 1848, abolished 1856, Mexico, abolished 1823, restored 1861,abolished 1865. Spain abolished 1871, restored 1874, abolished again 1931, restored officially under Franco 1947. England, Scotland and Ireland, abolished 1649, restored 1660. Cambodia: abolished 1970, restored 1993

Comment: And there are plenty of examples of states that started off as republics and became monarchies later on: Netherlands, founded as Republic 1567, became monarchy 1805. The Napoleonic Kingdom of Italy was founded as a republic in 1802 (under that name) and became a monarchy in 1805. Lucca-founded as a republic, later became a monarchy. Duchy of Florence-founded as Republic, later became monarchy. Iceland-founded as a republic, annexed to Norway, later became a monarchy in personal union with Denmark 1918-1944, then became a republic again.

Answer (score 1):

Albania is an example: it had a very complicated history in the early twentieth century. The [Provisional Government of Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisional_Government_of_Albania) was established in 1912 as part of the Balkan Wars which removed the Ottoman Empire from almost all of the Balkans. That was followed by a monarchy, the [Principality of Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Albania), 1913-25, under a German prince, and then the [Albanian Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_Republic) from 1925-28.

Ahmet Zogu was Prime Minister of the Principality, 1922-25, the sole President of the Republic, then became [King Zog I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zog_I_of_Albania) in 1928 as monarch of the [Kingdom of Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_Kingdom_(1928%E2%80%931939)). This lasted until spring 1939, when Italy took over Albania and the former royal family went into exile. Zog was not related to the German prince, or the Ottoman Emperors. For extra complexity, it appears that the English sportsman C B Fry was [offered the throne of Albania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._B._Fry#Politics) in the early 1920s.

Another example is the [French Second Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Second_Republic) from 1848-51. It was formed in a revolution against the French monarchy, which had been restored after the downfall of Napoleon I. Its president was [Charles-Louis Napoléon Bonaparte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_III), the nephew of Napoleon I, who seized power in 1851 and established the [Second French Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_French_Empire), which lasted until its defeat in the Franco-Prussian war of 1870-71, following which France has had three further distinct republics, and several interim administrations.